# List running services

Tags: services, grep

I am trying to get a list of the running services. I ran

```
service --status-all
```

It will return something like

```
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ ? ]  alsa-utils
 [ + ]  apache2
 [ + ]  atd
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ ? ]  binfmt-support
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  bootlogd
 [ - ]  bootlogs
```

I try to grep and it tries to work with the special characters.

```
sudo service --status-all | grep '+'
```

Is there anything that i can do to get it to work correctly.

Comment: try with `sudo service --status-all | grep -L '+'` because the `'` already says that it won't be escape character...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I try to grep and it tries to work with the special characters.

With [basic regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) (BRE) enabled (the default in absence of the switches `-E`, `-F` or `-P`), grep interprets the plus character as a literal `+`.

The problem is that only lines that begin with `[ + ]` or `[ - ]` get sent to [STDOUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29), while lines that begin with `[ ? ]` get sent to [STDERR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29). Only STDOUT gets piped to grep; STDERR gets printed directly on the terminal.

To obtain the output you're expecting, execute the following command:

```
service --status-all 2>&1 | grep '+'
```

`2>&1` sends STDERR to STDOUT, so grep is able to filter it.

Since you're printing only lines begnning with  `[ + ]`  , you might as well filter that part out. To do so, you can use the `-o` switch to print only matched output, the `-P` switch to enable [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (PCRE) and a look-behind assertion (`(?<=...)`):

```
service --status-all 2>&1 | grep -Po '(?<= \[\ \+ \]  ).*'
```

Note that with PCRE, you have to escape the plus sign and the brackets with a backslash.

The same result can be achieved with BRE, without look-behinds and without knowing the exact number of spaces if you use [sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed):

```
service --status-all 2>&1 | grep '+' | sed 's/.*] *//'
```

Here, the BRE `.*] *` (everything up to the right bracket, followed by any number of spaces) gets replaced by the empty string.

Comment: thanks great answer is there any way to remove the [ + ]

Comment: @WojonsTech: I've updated my answer.